# JavaScript Swap Image onClick (multiple instances of same image on page)

Tags: javascript, onclick

Trying to get the  to swap image onclick on each time I place within the page (six currently). I believe I use data-id="" in the  but am unsure how to adjust javascript to allocate each data-id per img tag to be unique. Thank you for help.

```
    <img id="like" src="img/icon-like.svg" onclick="swapImage();" width="16px">


    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
    var q=0; function swapImage(){ if(q==0){ document.getElementById("like").setAttribute('src','img/icon-liked.svg'); q++; }
    else{ document.getElementById("like").setAttribute('src','img/icon-like.svg'); q--; } }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<img id="like" src="img/icon-like.svg" onclick="swapImage();" width="16px">


    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">

var q=0; 
function swapImage(){ 
    document.querySelector("#like").setAttribute('src','img/icon-liked'+ q + '.svg');
  q++;
}
    </script>
```

Now go ahead and rename each of your individual images as "icon-liked0", "icon-liked1' and it will assign each of them.

**Warning:** this will only work through the six images once.

If you want it to loop through do this:

```
<img id="like" src="img/icon-like.svg" onclick="swapImage();" width="16px">


    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">

var q=0; 
function swapImage(){ 
    document.querySelector("#like").setAttribute('src','img/icon-liked'+ q + '.svg');
  q++;
  if (q == 6) {
    q = 0;
  }
}
    </script>
```

Comment: Tried both versions. First use turns on. (on/off would be useful) All others do not function at all. They are contained in modals. Here is link (I should have provided before so you had better context. apologies.)  http://cnnctd.co/example/landingpage-drk.html

Comment: So do you want only one `<div>` the switches between six images?

Comment: I just want that as you open each modal (post) that can click heart on (red) and then off (gray). First modal (post) works correctly, but rest are ignored.